# ¿Qué hacen las siguientes lineas de código en Java?

Tags: java

Buenos dias una pregunta, ¿que hace las siguientes lineas de codigo?

```
public static void main (String[] ars) {
    int suma = 0;
    for (int x=1;x<=100;x++) {          
        if (x%2!=0) suma+=x;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles líneas en específico?

Comment: en si todo el metodo main

Comment: Hola, cual es el objetivo de esta pregunta, veo que tienes conocimientos en Java, en verdad desconoces el funcionamiento de estas lineas?, saludos.

Comment: if (x%2!=0) suma+=x; no entiendo esta linea de codigo

Comment: Aquí la doc oficial sobre operadores aritméticos en [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: if (x%2!=0) suma+=x;  Lo que hace es dividir x entre 2 y si el reciduo de esa division da como resultado un numero diferente de cero,  entonces suma a la variable: "suma" lo que tiene en la variable "x", y lo que hay en la variable "x"  son puros numeros impares del uno al cien

Comment: Revisa la documentación que te comparte @Aprendiz , saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí una explicación de lo que hace el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // INICIALIZA LA VARIABLE "suma" CON 0 
    int suma = 0;
    // SE ITERA DE 1 AL 100 CON SALTOS DE 1
    for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        // VERIFICA QUE LOS NUMEROS NO SEAN PARES CON EL MODULO(%)
        if (x % 2 != 0)
            suma += x; // LA VARIABLE "suma" ACUMULA LA SUMA DE TODOS LOS NUMEROS IMPARES
    }
}
```

En este caso se irán sumando los números de la serie:

```
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + ... + 99 = 2500
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se esta ejecutando en esas lineas de código es que la variable "x" que se declara dentro de los paréntesis del "for" tome los valores del 0 al 100 y luego de que "x" asuma un valor, pregunta si el numero no es par y al no serlo le suma a la variable "suma" el valor que "x" tenga en ese momento. Esa es la función del "for" recorrer un rango, haciendo que una variable en este caso "x" tome todos los valores del principio del rango hasta el final.